# Bit field storage of color in red black tree

Tags: algorithm, indexing, data-structures, bit-fields, red-black-tree

Instead of storing the color attribute as a bool, lets say you wanted to use structs of bit fields. This way the color only takes 1 bit when a bool may take an entire byte.

If each bit struct is 8 bits, how would you map them to the nodes in the tree?

I’m writing C++ but this could be psuedocode or anything that supports bit fields.

Comment: That's the problem: each tree node needs that one bit, so if it's not stored in the node itself you need some kind of indexing scheme to find it, which would likely negate the savings you were getting by not having it in the node.

Comment: Right the savings isn’t even that great. I’m just scratching my head trying to come up with an indexing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to store all the nodes in an array.

In general this is not ideal because the node pointers can move (i.e. when you add a node and resize the the underlying vector) and also it's a bit harder to delete nodes.

If you do implement it this way then each node will have a index in the array that you can reuse in your bitfield. This is an implicit reference so it doesn't take more space.

Besides the previously mentioned issues this approach also breaks encapsulation, all for saving ~63 bits per entry (in the best case scenario where the compiler alocates 64 bits to store your field, common on today's hardware, in practice it might be smaller).

If you are really concerned about space, look for a data structure optimized for space (one that doesn't store two pointers for every entry).

Answer (score 0):

I use aligned nodes (that is, each node is at least 2-byte aligned although usually more) and then use the low bit of one of the held node pointers to store the color value. This does make retrieving and updating those pointers somewhat more complicated.

With the allocators my libraries use (MSVC) I get the required alignment for free.